# Why Does the Behavior of Matching.ImplementedInterfaces Differ from Matching.ExactType and FrozenAttribute.As?

Tags: c#, autofixture

Please consider the following code:

```
public class TestingSample
{
    public class FactoryClass : Class {}

    public class Class : IInterface {}

    public interface IInterface {}

    public class AutoData : AutoDataAttribute
    {
        public AutoData() : base( Create() ) {}

        static IFixture Create()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            fixture.Customize<IInterface>( composer => composer.FromFactory( () => new FactoryClass() ) );
            fixture.Customize<Class>( composer => composer.FromFactory( () => new FactoryClass() ) );
            return fixture;
        }
    }

    [Theory, TestingSample.AutoData]
    public void OldSkool( [Frozen( As = typeof(IInterface) )]Class first, Class second, IInterface third )
    {
        Assert.IsType<FactoryClass>( first );
        Assert.Same( first, second );
        Assert.Same( first, third );
    }

    [Theory, TestingSample.AutoData]
    public void DirectBaseType( [Frozen( Matching.ExactType )]Class first, Class second )
    {
        Assert.IsType<FactoryClass>( first );
        Assert.Same( first, second );
    }

    [Theory, TestingSample.AutoData]
    public void ImplementedInterfaces( [Frozen( Matching.ImplementedInterfaces )]Class first, IInterface second )
    {
        Assert.IsType<FactoryClass>( first );
        Assert.Same( first, second ); // The Fails.
    }
}
```

As you can (hopefully) see, the `ImplementedInterfaces` test fails.  Since `FrozenAttribute.As` has been deprecated and users have been directed to move to the Match enumeration, my expectation would be that it would behave the same as before.

However, it does appear that `Match.ImplementedInterfaces` behaves differently from both `Match.ExactType` and `FrozenAttribute.As`.

I did do some spelunking and saw that `Match.ExactType` and `FrozenAttribute.As` make use of the `SeedRequestSpecification` whereas `Match.ImplementedInterfaces` only matches on `Type` requests.

Would it be possible to get some context around this behavior?  Is this by design?  And if so, is there a known recommendation to design in such a way to restore the old behavior using `Match.ImplementedInterfaces`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a proviso: the code as supplied in the OP doesn't behave *quite* as described, on my machine, using AutoFixture 3.39.0. The difference is that the first assertion in this test *passes:*

```
[Theory, TestingSample.AutoData]
public void ImplementedInterfaces(
    [Frozen(Matching.ImplementedInterfaces)]Class first,
    IInterface second)
{
    Assert.IsType<FactoryClass>(first); // passes
    Assert.Same(first, second); // fails
}
```

Still, I grant that it's (a bit) surprising that the second assertion fails.

The short explanation is that with the current implementation, freezing is done at reflection-time, not at run-time. When *AutoFixture.Xunit2* figures out to what to freeze, it looks at the type of the parameter on which the `[Frozen]` attribute is applied. This is `Class`, not `FactoryClass`, so the result is that `FactoryClass` isn't frozen at all!

You can see this from this test:

```
[Theory, TestingSample.AutoData]
public void FactoryClassIsNotFrozen(
    [Frozen(Matching.ImplementedInterfaces)]Class first,
    FactoryClass second)
{
    Assert.IsType<FactoryClass>(first); // passes
    Assert.IsType<FactoryClass>(second); // passes
    Assert.Same(first, second); // fails
}
```

Is this the best possible implementation? Perhaps not, but that's how it currently works. There's [an open issue in the AutoFixture GitHub repository](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/420) suggesting that the freeze implementation should be refactored to work more like a DI Container's Singleton lifetime. This may change the behaviour in this particular scenario towards something that fits it better. Whether or not it'll have some disadvantages as well I can't tell at the moment.

When we redesigned the `[Frozen]` attribute to use the more flexible `Matching` rules, I was aware that the new system wouldn't be able to be a 100% replacement for the old `As` property. I still think the trade-off was worth the while.

While `As` enables you to get this particular feature to work, it's because you, as the programmer, *know* that `Class` implements `IInterface`, and therefore the `[Frozen(As = typeof(IInterface))]` annotation is meaningful.

You could argue that `As` is more flexible, but it's mainly because it has no built-in intelligence. You could also have written `[Frozen(As = typeof(IAsyncResult))]` and that would have compiled just fine - only to fail at run-time because it's utter nonsense.

> is there a known recommendation to design in such a way to restore the old behavior using Match.ImplementedInterfaces?

Yes, consider simplifying the design of the System Under Test (SUT).

AutoFixture was originally conceived as a Test-Driven Development tool, and that's still its main purpose. In the spirit of [GOOS](http://bit.ly/growingoos), we should **listen to the tests**. If the test is difficult to write, the first reaction should be to simplify the SUT. AutoFixture tends to amplify such feedback from tests.

Do you really need to match something that both implements an interface and derives from a base class? Why?

Could it be made simpler?

Comment: Fantastic, comprehensive answer (as always!) @mark-seemann.  Much appreciated. You are indeed correct about the proviso/incorrectly (marked) failed test.  That was a mistake in how I was reading the results (without actually clicking the line to verify).  To get at the core of the issue, it is most likely because I am still learning TDD and testing in general, but much like mocking, I like the idea of using a factory to create my SUT (or supporting objects) and using it within the test.  That is the core of the issue here: to create an item from a factory and freeze it (as a singleton).